# Função que verifica se um vetor está em ordem crescente

Tags: c, algoritmo

Estou fazendo um exercício que diz:

> Critique o código da seguinte função, que promete decidir se o vetor
>   v[0..n-1] está em ordem crescente.

```
int verifica (int v[], int n) {     //n é o tamanho do vetor
if (n > 1) 
   for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
      if (v[i-1] > v[i]) 
         return 0;     
      return 1; 
 }
```

Já testei com vários casos e aparenta estar certo. Há algo errado na função?

Aqui a `main()` que fiz para testar:

```
int main(){

    int vetor[5] = {-1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; //pode ser mudado para ler os valores

    if(verifica(vetor, 5)){
        printf("Esta em ordem crescente");
    } else{
        printf("Nao esta em ordem crescente");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, o código está certo, mas não está legível, é muito fácil acha r que ele faz uma coisa e faz outra. Note que o código é o mesmo, mas está mais simples e mais legível na versão compacta e na mais explícita na organização dos blocos. Até o espaços fazem diferença na legibilidade. E nomes bons evitam comentários.

Em condições normais o antes `n` nunca deveria ser menor que 1, o `if` só faz sentido se tiver erro no argumento. E mesmo que venha isso, verificar e não verificar desta forma dá na mesma. Se seria o caso dele existir se for para dar erro de argumento inválido.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int EstaOrdemCrescente(int vetor[], int tamanho) {
    for (int i = 1; i < tamanho; i++) if (vetor[i - 1] > vetor[i]) return 0;
    return 1; 
 }
 
 int main() {
     printf(EstaOrdemCrescente((int[]){-1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 5) ? "Esta em ordem crescente\n" : "Nao esta em ordem crescente\n");
     printf(EstaOrdemCrescente((int[]){-1, 2, 0, 4, 5}, 5) ? "Esta em ordem crescente\n" : "Nao esta em ordem crescente\n");
     printf(EstaOrdemCrescente((int[]){1}, 0) ? "Esta em ordem crescente\n" : "Nao esta em ordem crescente\n");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hQw5Nq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jhyeiavk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/SortingStyle.c).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int EstaOrdemCrescente(int vetor[], int tamanho) {
    for (int i = 1; i < tamanho; i++) {
        if (vetor[i - 1] > vetor[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1; 
 }
 
 int main() {
     printf(EstaOrdemCrescente((int[]){-1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 5) ? "Esta em ordem crescente\n" : "Nao esta em ordem crescente\n");
     printf(EstaOrdemCrescente((int[]){-1, 2, 0, 4, 5}, 5) ? "Esta em ordem crescente\n" : "Nao esta em ordem crescente\n");
     printf(EstaOrdemCrescente((int[]){1}, 0) ? "Esta em ordem crescente\n" : "Nao esta em ordem crescente\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O codigo correto é esse:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int levetor(int v[],int &n){       //função lê vetor

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)

cin>>v[i];
}

bool verificacrescente(int v[],int n){

if(n>1){

    int cont=1;

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){

        if(v[i-1]<v[i]){

            cont++;

        }else{

            return 1;
            }
        }
   }
        if(n==cont){

            return 0;
        }
}
int main(){

 int n1;

 cin>>n1;

 int v1[n1];

 levetor(v1,n1);

if (verificacrescente (v1,n1)==false)

    cout<<"Vetor esta ordenado";

if (verificacrescente (v1,n1)==true)

    cout<<"Vetor nao esta ordenado";

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Seu código está semi-completo, ele faz exatamente o que devia fazer, o problema é o return que você botou, assim q ele compara os 2 primeiros numeros ele termina a função como true. O correto seria algo como:

```
int verifica (int v[], int n) {
   int k = 1;
   if (n > 1){
      for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
         if (v[i-1] > v[i]){
            k++;
         }
         else{
            return 1;
         }
      }
   }
   if (k == n){
       return 0;
   }
}
```

Dessa forma ele vai acumulando os "acertos" em k, ou seja, se o valor anterior for mesmo maior que o próximo... E assim até chegar no ultimo termo n.

Se ele chegar no ultimo termo n e for igual a k, significa que ele percorreu toda a lista sem retornar 1, então a lista é toda crescente. Se houvesse algum elemento fora de ordem, ele iria cair no return 1 e não seria uma lista crescente.

Comment: não, ele não para depois dos dois primeiros... testei com algo tipo {1, 2, 3, 8, 4} e realmente retorna que não está ordenado. Talvez tenha ficado meio confuso por estar sem { no for e if (a função não é minha, foi dada no exercício, por isso não estou entendendo onde está o erro)

Comment: testou o meu codigo também? O return para a função onde estiver e retorna o que foi pedido.

Answer (score -3):

```
 Uma outra solução com printf's a acompanhar:
        
        include <stdio.h>    
        int verifica_ordem(int x[], int sz){
                int k=0;
                for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
                    printf("v[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]);
                    if(x[i]<x[i-1]){
                        printf("enter v[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]);
                        
                        printf ("array  = %d ciclos\n", k);
                        return 0;
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                printf ("array  = %d ciclos\n", k);
                return 1;
            }
            
            int main(){
                int a[]={4,5,6,7,8};
                int b[]={1,2,3,0,5,6};
                if(verifica_ordem(a,5)){
                    printf("Array 'a' ordenado\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("Array 'a' nao esta ordenado\n");
                }
                if(verifica_ordem(b,6)){
                    printf("Array 'b' ordenado\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("Array 'b' nao esta ordenado\n");
                }
                return 0;
            }
    
    outra solução usando ciclo while e printf's :
    
    int verifica_ordem(int x[], int sz){
        int i = 0;
        int k = 0;
        while(i<sz){
            printf("v[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]);
            if(x[i]<x[i-1]){
                printf("enter v[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]);
                
                printf ("array  = %d ciclos\n", k);
                return 0;
            }
            i++;k++;
            
            
        }
        printf ("array  = %d ciclos\n", k);
        return 1;
    }
    int main(){
        int a[]={4,5,6,7,8};
        int b[]={1,2,3,0,5,6};
        if(verifica_ordem(a,5)){
            printf("Array 'a' ok!\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Array 'a' not ok\n");
        }
        if(verifica_ordem(b,6)){
            printf("Array 'b' ok!\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Array 'b' not ok!\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```